# Update after Insert SQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My end goal is to UPDATE an existing column (promo_ids) in the Dealers table with the new PK ID created once a new Promotion is inserted.  I want to keep the existing IDs that have already been set.  Is this possible to do?  If so, any point in the right direction would be great.  I'm still pretty new to SQL statements.  Here's the code I currently have to add a new promotion.

```
public function add_new_promo() {
      global $wpdb;

      $result = $wpdb->query(
                  $wpdb->prepare(
                    "
                    INSERT INTO $wpdb->gdp_promos
                    (promo, short_desc, long_desc, rebate_url, legal_copy, image_id, promo_headline, promo_line1, promo_desc, linkback_url, share_image_id, dealer_ids)
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                    ",
                    $this->promo_data['promo'],
                    $this->promo_data['short_desc'],
                    $this->promo_data['long_desc'],
                    $this->promo_data['rebate_url'],
                    $this->promo_data['legal_copy'],
                    $this->promo_data['image_id'],
                    $this->promo_data['promo_line1'],
                    $this->promo_data['promo_headline'],
                    $this->promo_data['promo_desc'],
                    $this->promo_data['linkback_url'],
                    $this->promo_data['share_image_id'],
                    $this->promo_data['dealer_ids']
                  )
                );
      if ( $result === false ) {
          $state = 'error';
          $msg = __( 'There was a problem saving the new promo details, please try again.', 'gdp' );
      } else {
          $_POST = array();
          $state = 'updated';
          $msg = __( "promo {$this->promo_data['promo']} successfully added.", 'gdp' );
      }
      add_settings_error ( 'add-promo', esc_attr( 'add-promo' ), $msg, $state );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is by either using a `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` on `Promotion` table (OR) by wrapping both the `insert` and `update` statement in a transaction block inside a stored procedure. You can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the newly inserted PK ID column value if the `ID` column is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.

Refer `MySQL` documentation for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

In your else block , add:

```
$new_pk_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
$update_stmt = "UPDATE Dealers SET promos_id = %d WHERE dealer_id = %d";
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare($update_stmt, array($new_pk_id, $specific_dealer_id));
```

Comment: This looks like it will update every dealer in the dealer's table with the new Promo ID while erasing all existing Promo IDs.